# Relation between p-norms and metric tensors in finite-dimension

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, tensors

I need your help.

I am trying to learn some differential geometry, but I get stuck when I figure out the following:

In a Euclidean space ${\mathbb{R}^n}$ (a finite-dimensional vector space over ${\mathbb{R}}$), is there a way to write down a metric tensor that induces the finite-dimensional p-norm ($\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{{\left| {{x^i}} \right|}^p}}$ , where the ${{x^i}}$ are the contravariant components of vector $\overrightarrow x $ in the standard orthonormal basis $\overrightarrow {{e_i}} $) ?

I know the question above may already have a simple answer (that I have been unable to browse, though), but I am still at the beginning, thus I would really appreciate any hint or standard reference.

Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: you can only do it for $p=2$, because otherwise it doesn't have the right homogeneity (a metric tensor is bilinear, so $g(cx,cx)=c^2g(x,x)$).

Comment: Ok, thank you. It's clear. For the sake of curiosity, do you know if there is some (probably non-linear) operator that does the job of the metric tensor for l^p spaces? (with 'does the job' I mean that it connects the space and its dual, allowing to raise/lower indices). ThanX again